# MIMIC-III: When exactly was MIMIC-III v1.3 released?

Tags: mimic-iii

What is the release history for MIMIC-III?
I was using some version and now I see there is version 1.3.
When was 1.3 officially released?
When was 1.2 officially released?

Are there other versions?

Do you expect a new release very often? Or will now the time between releases be longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When was 1.3 officially released? When was 1.2 officially released?

MIMIC-III v1.3 was released on 10 December 2015. MIMIC-III v1.2 was released on 20 November 2015.

> What is the release history for MIMIC-III? Are there other versions?

The first version of MIMIC-III v1.0 was made available on 25 August 2015. For an outline of the release history for MIMIC-III, see the [release notes](http://mimic.physionet.org/about/releasenotes/) page of the [MIMIC website](http://mimic.physionet.org/).

> Do you expect a new release very often? Or will now the time between releases be longer?

We expect MIMIC-III to become increasingly stable over time, with progressively long intervals between updates. We do however plan to make releases for as long as there are bugs and usability issues to be addressed and there is new data to add.

Comment: I very much like that mimic3 team chose to use StackExchange for questions!!! Thanks